# Equivalence of Definitions on Locally Compact Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm a beginner in General Topology and I am finding locally compact spaces quite confusing. There are several definitions given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) and every other author seems to come up with their own. There are other definitions which I came across and I'm wondering whether the following definitions are equivalent to the ones given in Wikipedia.

**Definition G.** A topological space $X$ is said to be locally compact if for each $x\in X$ and each open set $U$ containing $x$, there is some compact set $A$ such that $x\in A^{\circ}\subseteq A\subseteq U$.

**Definition M.** A topological space $X$ is said to be locally compact if there is a base $\mathscr B$ such that $\overline B$ is compact for every $B\in \mathscr B$. This is equivalent to saying that for each $x\in X$ and each open set $U$ containing $x$, there is some open set $B\in \mathscr B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$ and $\overline B$ is compact.

It is clear to me that Definition $G$ is equivalent of Definition $3'$ of Wikipedia. It is also clear to me that Definition $M$ implies Definition $2'$ of Wikipedia. Now, I wonder if they are equivalent. Definition $2''$ says that at each point $x\in X$, we can find a local base $\mathscr N_x$ of relatively compact sets. So given $x\in X$ and $U\subseteq X$ open set containing $x$, we can find $B\in \mathscr N_x$ and some open set $V$ such that $x\in V \subseteq B\subseteq U$ such that $\overline B$ is compact. But $B$ may not be open here so it makes me wonder if they are equivalent.

Are Definitions M and Definition $2'$ equivalent? Any hints on proving or disproving it will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working without assumptions on $X$ (like Hausdorffness etc):

Definition 2’ only says that each point $x$ just has one relatively compact neighbourhood and M is much stronger: this implies that within *each* open subset $O$ that  contains $x$, there is an *open* neighbourhood $B$ (base sets are open) that is relatively compact (but it is not necessarily ensured that actually $\overline{B}$ is a subset of $O$, which is what we often want). So applying definition M to $X$ shows that M implies 2’ while the reverse does not always hold: The Aleksandrov extension $\alpha \Bbb Q$ of the rationals obeys 2’ (the whole space works as a neighbourhood for any point), but not M, as points in $\Bbb Q$ don’t have small compact neighbourhoods.

Comment: By any chance, is M equivalent to $3$? I'm (almost) certain that it isn't.

Comment: @ashK It implies $3$ for sure. And in a KC space the reverse clearly holds too. So it must be a pretty weird space to have a counterexample to $3$ implies $M$ I think.

Comment: So, do you expect that they're equivalent?

Comment: @ashK No they’re not. The included point topology (wrt $0$ say) on $\Bbb Z$ is an example where $3$ holds ($n$ has the compact neighbourhood $\{n,0\}$) but M does not (the closure of every non-empty open set is $X$, which is not compact).

Comment: That works but that wasn't a weird space though.

Comment: @ashK well, not even $T_1$ is quite weird. But it’s a standard example so familiar in that respect.